# Is there a fix? CiviCRM upgrade to 5.23.0 breaks payment processor

Tags: civievent, civicrm-event

On a Joomla! 3.9.15 system, after upgrading from CiviCRM 5.22.0 to 5.23.0 payment processing for fails for both paypal (credit card) and pay later options. When either is selected,  the request for additional information (e.g. credit card selection, billing address, etc) is not display and the 'submit' for the form no longer works (it gets grayed out). The work-around is go back to version 5.22.0 (with the 5.23.0 database). The payment processing and form submission then works.

Comment: Try clearing the templates_c folder and if that doesn't work look in the browser console (developer tools) if there's any errors.

Comment: And please report back whether the suggestion @Demerit gives you works!  If not this will need to be escalated.

Comment: I have tried yesterday to do the upgrade on Joomla, but the database-upgrade script did not proceed. I have tried to update the database updates with phpMyAdmin with the statement in the upgrade-script but the statement: ALTER TABLE civicrm_payment_processor ALTER COLUMN is_active SET DEFAULT 1; Is reported as wrong. {* file to handle db changes in 5.23.alpha1 during upgrade *}

Comment: Clearing the templates_c folder doesn't resolve the issue. The console reports an error, but I've not found a way to attach a file here since the error output is too large to include here within a comment. It's been suggested to delete lines 122-133 from the CRM/Core/Resources.php file. Doing so resolved the issue, but may not be a good solution. https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/1143a7815b1abbcb7cfc0cab6c754e499d11d064